# codeigniter returns "Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$load" trying to load helper lib

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

[image]

**Background Information**

I just installed a fresh copy of CI and modified the welcome controller to include the url Helper so I can call the method `base_url`.  I then try to call this method from `home.php`

**Problem:**
I'm getting the following error message:

```
Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$load
Filename: controllers/welcome.php
```

**Code:**

This is what my welcome controller now looks like:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');     
    }   

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width">    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- Le styles -->    
    <title>test site</title>
    <script>   
      var BASEPATH = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
    </script>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/navbar.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">    
  </head>
```

The system is dying on the line in the controller's constructor where i try to load the library...

What I've done so far:

1. Read the manual. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html
2. Tried to include the url library in the config/autoload.php like so:

   `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

But I'm still getting the error. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Screenshots:

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You forgot a crucial thing;

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); //Loading url helper    
    }   

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home'); //Loading home view
    }
}
```

The `parent::__construct`. If you don't do that; the Controller will not inherit it's abstract layer when you override the __construct in your own controller.

As long as you don't override your `__construct` it's all ok. It only happens when you override it. You don't have the `load` functionality because the Welcome class is empty (no inheritance), even if it extends the `CI_Controller` (but with a `__construct` override).

Comment: it makes sense... Unfortunately though, that's giving me another error. Please check Edit 1 section of my post.

Comment: Haha you copied my line literally. I made a typo. It should be `;` instead of `:` `parent::__construct();`