# CodeIgniter linking to another page/controler

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

I am a beginner in CodeIgniter framework and I have problem with links. I found a couple of pages in which is explained how to link pages, but from some reason I have  problem to link two pages. I did this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller_proffesor') ?>">Insert Labwork</a>
```

and that should call controller_proffesor method :

```
function index(){
    $this->load->view('proffesor_view_insert_labwork');
}
```

i try also this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller_proffesor/index') ?>">Insert Labwork</a>
```

but when i click on that link this is what i get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Controller_proffesor::$load
Filename: controllers/controller_proffesor.php
Line Number: 7
Backtrace:
```

i have also include this line in my autoload file :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to add also html in your autoload helper? if not kindly do so.

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');

but even this does not solve the problem, reports the same error .

Line Number: 7 where he sees the error is this line :

    $this->load->view('proffesor_view_insert_labwork');

Comment: do you really have this professor_view_insert_labwork php file?

Comment: where did you save it? in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the constructor have you added:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Try adding it inside __construct(). It invokes the constructor of inherited parent class CI_Controller.

Your code should look like this..

```
class Controller_proffesor extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //followed by your helper, model load statements
    }
```

NOTE: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21339891/5176188 for more details. This may be a duplicate question.

Comment: unfortunately no, when I added this constructor:
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    } 
This is the error that occurs: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent

Filename: controllers/controller_proffesor.php

Line Number: 7

Backtrace:

Comment: Have you inherited CI_Controller class? If no, Add ***extends CI_Controller*** after *class Controller_proffesor*

Comment: I did not extend CI_Controller

Comment: Try extending CI_Controller. Refer to my answer, and also to the other answer I linked with the edit.

Comment: I just extend ci_controller and that solves the problem. I cannot believe that i did not see that, Thanks!
Just tell me how to refer to your answer

Comment: Good to know it worked. By refer I just meant have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your config file you must set something like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');
```

In the controller, you must forget to extend it and the name also must concide with the name of your class and it is also like the model extends it to `CI_Model`

```
Class Class_Name extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct () {
      parent::__construct    
      // you can load here the session and models
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.