# A PHP Error was encountered severity:8192 I'm getting the error

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future verisons of PHP, login has a deprecated constructor severity:8192

I get an error in line 3rd and 26th line in the login php file
26th line error: undefined property:login::$load 
I'm getting the error

**MY CODE**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class login extends CI_Controller {

```
/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}
function login(){
    $data ["title"] = "CodeIgniter Simple Login Form with session";
    $this->load->view("login", data);

}
function login_validation(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Kullanýcý Adý', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        if($this->login_model->can_login($username, $password))
        {

            $session_data = array(

                'username'  => $username

            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            redirect(base_url("login/enter"));

        }else{
            $this->session->flash_data('error' , 'Invalid Username and Password');
            redirect(base_url("login"));

        }
    }else
        {
            $this->login();
    }
    function enter()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('username') != ''){
            redirect(base_url("dashboard"));

        }else{
                redirect(base_url("login"));
        }

    }


}
```

}
?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter returns "Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$load" trying to load helper lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339820/codeigniter-returns-message-undefined-property-welcomeload-trying-to-load)

Comment: load `url` helper in your controller or in `autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

**Note** : Controller name should start with capital letter only

Load `url` helper first like this :

*In `autoload.php`*

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

*Or load in your `Login` controller like this :*

```
class Login extends CI_Controller 
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
   }
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: did u check my answer? is it helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not name a function of a class the same as the class. You have a function `login()` and the class is named `login` which triggers the warning on line 3. When PHP sees class and function names that match it thinks the function is the constructor for the class. But that's not what you want and is the reason you get the error on line 26.

There does not seem to be any reason for a constructor in your class. (Unless you really do need to load a helper or other library)

To fix your problem delete the `index()` function then rename `login()` to `index()`. Finally, use an uppercase L in the name of the class. So change this

```
class login extends CI_Controller {
```

to this

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
```

The file name should also have an uppercase first letter i.e. `Login.php`